# What is the correct discretization of an integral differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

Given an integral differential euqation:

$y'(t) + \int_{t_o}^ty(s)ds + y(t)= 0$

We can easily discretize $y'(t) = y_o $ as $\dfrac{y(t+h)-y(t)}{h} = y_o \Rightarrow y(t+h)-y(t) = hy_o$. Taking $\lim h \to 0$  immediately yields the former.

How do you deal with the integral?

What is the proper discretization of the integral differential equation as shown above?

Comment: You have some ambiguity in your problem statement:  In the integrand, "$y(t)$", is that $t$ the dummy variable of integration, or the upper limit of the integral?  I assume the former, but I've been wrong before.

Comment: In this particular case, you can simply differentiate the equation to derive the ordinary differential equation $y'' + y + y' = 0$, which may be solved explicitly. Of course that is not possible in the general case. But special solutions such as this one may be used to assess the accuracy of  discretization schemes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be taking a step size of $h$.  This suggests partitioning the integral on $\{t_0 + k h | k \in \Bbb{Z} \text{ and } 0 \leq k \leq (t-t_0)/h\}$.  Then which values of $y(t_0 + k h)$ you sum to get the value of your integral depends on whether you want to take left sums ($k = 0, 1, 2, \dots,  (t-t_0)/h - 1 $) or right sums ($k = 1, 2, 3 \dots, (t-t_0)/h$) in your Riemann sum.  Then, assuming $y$ is Riemann integrable, taking the limit $h \rightarrow 0$ is the integral you've written.

It's more useful, however, to realize that you don't need to repeatedly re-sum.  The integral can be treated as a running sum of the approximate $y$s that you have generated.  Don't forget to scale by the current step size.  (That is, you're summing areas of rectangles.  This is "more important" to remember when you have an adaptive step size.)